# Should `make clean` remove submodules and third-party packages?

Tags: build, makefile

I'm fairly new to Makefiles. I'm unsure of the standard semantics of `make clean`. Which of the following is correct?

- **`make clean` should remove all files that were built from other files in the repository.** For example:

  ```
  clean:
      @rm -rf dist
  ```
- **`make clean` should remove all files that were built from other files in the repository, *or which were added by `make setup`*.** For example:

  ```
  clean:
      @rm -rf dist
      @rm -rf node_modules # remove npm packages installed by `setup`
  ```

Building one file from another generally doesn't require an Internet connection, but fetching third-party dependencies often does. This suggests that `make clean` should not remove third-party dependencies installed by `make setup`. If one has been modifying the source of a third-party dependency, though, perhaps blowing away these changes is exactly what one expects `make clean` to do.

Put another way, should `make clean` “undo” `make`, or should it undo `make setup && make`?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is up to you what your `make clean`  does. The rules you quoted are only conventions.

However, there are basically to reasons for calling `make clean`:

- Free as much as possible disk space, after everything is done.
- Allow a start over in case something is screwed up (e.g., time stamps) and the incremental build does not work anymore.

Regarding for the first case, depending on the semantics of "everything is done", both of your alternative could be justified. However, I would prefer `make uninstall` to redo (everything) of installation.

Comment: I like the idea of having `make uninstall` undo `make setup`, leaving `make clean` to undo `make`.